# best way to map a value from range number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say we have a data example like this:

| AQI | LEVEL |
| --- | --- |
| 0~50 | 1 |
| 51~100 | 2 |
| 101~150 | 3 |
| 151~200 | 4 |
| 201~300 | 5 |
| >300 | 6 |

What's the best way to return the Level of AQI by given a AQI value(ex:100, return 2)

```py
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    # do sth map idea like here
    return level_of_aqi
```

My current method:

```py
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    if 0 <= aqi <= 50:
        level = 1
    elif 51 <= aqi <= 100:
        level = 2
    ....

    return level
```

Is there any better way to improve ?

Comment: `return min((aqi+49)//50, 6)`

Comment: @TimRoberts Does not work for 0. Must be `max(1, min((aqi+49)//50, 6))`.

Comment: @DYZ It's a good answer and pretty close, but since ranges aren't all equal sizes, it may require a little modify here

Comment: @AndySu Good catch, i feel like the unequal ranges was missed by more people than just the three of us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the ranges aren't all equal sizes (for 1-4, the range is 50, but for 5 it is 100), you could use a generator expression with `sum()` like this:

```
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    return sum(l<=aqi for l in [0, 51, 101, 151, 201, 301])
```

This takes advantage of `True` having a value of `1` and `False` having a value of `0`

Here are example outputs:

```
In [1]: get_level_of_aqi(50)
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: get_level_of_aqi(100)
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: get_level_of_aqi(125)
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: get_level_of_aqi(220)
Out[4]: 5

In [5]: get_level_of_aqi(280)
Out[5]: 5

In [6]: get_level_of_aqi(310)
Out[6]: 6
```

Comment: I like this answer. With this method you can also perhaps make a list with all the ranges and thus simply change values in that list if your ranges changes. That should avoid a lot of hastle which would be caused in case of chained comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this implementation and let me know if it works for you.

```
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    if aqi > 0 and aqi <= 300:
        return (aqi-1)//50 + 1
    elif aqi >300:
        return 6
    else:
        raise Exception("Please pass positive numbers")
```

Please comment below if you need explanation for this. have a great day.

Comment: If you're gonna go with input validation, I'd suggest raising `ValueError`, as that is more specific. And then test input type as well. Either go full ham on input validation or don't bother, is my opinion :D

Comment: I havent tried but Im pretty sure this would not return 6 for aqi>300... Reason being the code would not reach the elif block because if aqi > 300 is true, then aqi is also > 0. The elif block should have been before the if block

Comment: yeah my bad, I am updating my code .

Comment: @FoCDoT FYI: Ranges aren't all equal sizes

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it has a dict mapping.

```
# mapping
d = {
    1: [0, 50],
    2: [51, 100],
    3: [101, 150],
    4: [151, 200],
    5: [201, 300]
}


def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    if aqi < 0:
        return None

    for k, v in d.items():
        if v[0] <= aqi <= v[1]:
            return k

    return 6  # above 300


aqi = -1
level = get_level_of_aqi(aqi)
print(f'aqi: {aqi}, level: {level}')


aqi = 60
level = get_level_of_aqi(aqi)
print(f'aqi: {aqi}, level: {level}')


aqi = 500
level = get_level_of_aqi(aqi)
print(f'aqi: {aqi}, level: {level}')

# aqi: -1, level: None
# aqi: 60, level: 2
# aqi: 500, level: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using range() if you just want to do straight compare

```
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    if aqi in range(0, 50 + 1):
        level = 1
    elif aqi in range(51, 100 + 1):
        level = 2
    elif aqi in range(101, 150 + 1):
        level = 3
    elif aqi in range(151, 200 + 1):
        level = 4
    elif aqi in range(201, 300 + 1):
        level = 5
    elif aqi > 300:
        level = 6
    else:
        raise Exception("Please pass positive numbers")
    return level
```

It may not be fancy but it's clear

Comment: chained comparisons would be even clearer

Comment: e.g., `if 0 <= aqi <= 50`, `if 50 < aqi <= 100`, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import ceil


def get_level_of_aqi(aqi: int):
    aqi = ceil((aqi or 1) / 50)
    aqi = aqi > 5 and aqi - 1 or aqi
    return min(aqi, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a binary tree, where each node contains a value, the left branch only values smaller than and the right branch only larger than that value. If your search item is smaller/larger than the item in a branch, you continue to search in the left/right tree. This is repeated until you cannot go further. If making sure the tree is balanced (e.g., red-black tree), maximum search time is O(log(n)). Alternatively, you can use binary search. But these solutions only pay off when you have really a lot categories and irregular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Write your if condition from heighest number.

```py
def get_level_of_aqi(aqi):
    level = None
    if aqi > 300:
        level = 6
    elif 201 <= aqi <= 300:
        level = 5
    elif 151 <= aqi <= 200:
        level = 4
    elif 101 <= aqi <= 150:
        level = 3
    elif 51 <= aqi <= 100:
        level = 2
    elif 0 <= aqi <= 50:
        level = 1

    return level


print(get_level_of_aqi(50))
1
print(get_level_of_aqi(52))
2
print(get_level_of_aqi(4555))
6
```